# Convert Aliased Paths in TS Declarations Files when Building with Webpack

Tags: webpack, alias, tsconfig, dts

Why imported modules in generated `.dts` files are preserving the aliased paths from `tsconfig.json` in `paths` option? How to fix it?

Actual: `@/codes/classes/apollo` (which cannot be resolved from my builds folder)

Expected: `./classes/apollo` (which can be resolved from builds folder)

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "builds",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxFactory": "Vue",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "scripthost"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "types": ["jest", "node", "vuetify", "webpack-env"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "codes/**/*.ts",
    "codes/**/*.tsx",
    "shims/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const HotModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack').HotModuleReplacementPlugin
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'codes', 'index.ts'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'codes', 'index.css')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'builds'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', 'jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname)
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              onlyCompileBundledFiles: true
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'stylus-loader',
            options: {
              preferPathResolver: 'webpack',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|oga|wav|webm|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'index.css'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'codes', 'index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'builds'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: true
  }
}

module.exports = config
```